# Unable to get Dataflow steps information using Java API

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to get the `steps` & `jobMetrics` information of **an active streaming job** using the following code:

```
val jobMetrics = dataflowClient.projects().jobs().getMetrics(projectId, jobId).execute().getMetrics
val steps = dataflowClient.projects().jobs().get(projectId, jobId).execute().getSteps
```

But, even though I am able to get the `jobMetrics` information, *the steps is always returning null.*
Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I'm Java illiterate but with regards to the details that you need I can point you to which endpoint in Dataflow API to get them. My examples are done by sending HTTP requests to the Dataflow API using curl.

To retrieve `steps` using Dataflow API use [projects.jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/get) endpoint and specify what [JobView](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/JobView) you want. **JOB_VIEW_ALL** is required to return [job.steps](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#Job.Step).

Sample curl command used:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/jobs/2022-01-13_19_11_56-999999999999?view=JOB_VIEW_ALL
```

Response snippet with `steps`:

[image]

---

But if following Dataflow Java API. You need to build your [GetJobRequest](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/com.google.dataflow.v1beta3.GetJobRequest) to include [setView()](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/com.google.dataflow.v1beta3.GetJobRequest.Builder#com_google_dataflow_v1beta3_GetJobRequest_Builder_setView_com_google_dataflow_v1beta3_JobView_) with [Enum JobView](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/com.google.dataflow.v1beta3.JobView) as the parameter. Using code snippet from [getJob() documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/com.google.dataflow.v1beta3.JobsV1Beta3Client#com_google_dataflow_v1beta3_JobsV1Beta3Client_getJob_com_google_dataflow_v1beta3_GetJobRequest_):

```
 try (JobsV1Beta3Client jobsV1Beta3Client = JobsV1Beta3Client.create()) {
   GetJobRequest request =
       GetJobRequest.newBuilder()
           .setProjectId("your-project")
           .setJobId("jobId101296568")
           .setView(JobView.forNumber(2)) // try 2 as value for JOB_VIEW_ALL as per Enum JobView documentation provided above
           .setLocation("us-central1")
           .build();
   Job response = jobsV1Beta3Client.getJob(request);
 }
```

Code snippet above should return [Job object](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/com.google.dataflow.v1beta3.Job) where you can try doing [getSteps()](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/com.google.dataflow.v1beta3.Job#com_google_dataflow_v1beta3_Job_getSteps_int_) and see if it will return something.